# Avoiding Log4j warning before Spring context loading

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j, slf4j

> I am working on a stand alone Java application and facing the below
>   log4j warning during start up of my application:

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

> However, I am able to see all the "spring related" logs after loading
>   the spring context (line 3 in main method below) i.e., the warning
>   comes even before loading the spring context, but after loading the
>   spring context, spring logs are being logged.

**I am providing my application Java main class & bean xml below:**

> ApplicationStarter (main Java Class):

```
public class ApplicationStarter {

    @Autowired
    private UserInputs userInputs;

    @Resource
    private volatile BlockingQueue<String> inputsQueue;

    public static void main(String[] args) {                        

        GenericXmlApplicationContext context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        context.setValidating(false);
        context.load("MyProject-Beans.xml");
        context.refresh();

        MyProjectBean myBeanObj = (MyProjectBean)(context.getBean("myProjectBean"));
        myBeanObj.startApplication();       
    }
}
```

> I have also got the below log4j code at the beginning of 
>   "MyProject-Beans.xml" file:

```
<bean id="log4jInitialization"   class=
 "org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">

  <property name="targetClass" 
   value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
    <property name="arguments">
     <list>
         <value>file:///{MYPROJECT_HOME}log4j.properties</value>
       </list>
    </property>
 </bean>
```

> My project log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.category.org.springframework=INFO,MYPROJECT_CONSOLE_LOGS
log4j.category.com.myproject=INFO,MYPROJECT_CONSOLE_LOGS
log4j.appender.MYPROJECT_CONSOLE_LOGS=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.MYPROJECT_CONSOLE_LOGS.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MYPROJECT_CONSOLE_LOGS.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p   
%C{1}:%M():%m\n
```

> > Currently I am supressing the warning by adding the below first line
> >     in the main() method.
>
> **org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org.springframework").setLevel(Level.OFF);**

**However, I don't like this line as it is hard coding the spring logger inside the application class.
I would like to know if there is any better way of removing the Spring Log4j warning during the start up by preserving the spring log4j level property outside of the application.**

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why aren't you defining it in your log4j.properties file?

Comment: @Koby:  I already have the log4j.properties (which is loaded from spring beans xml file) in the project. FYI, I have added the log4j.properties file content above.

Answer (score 3):

This warning is telling us, that log4j.properties can't be found in your classpath at runtime. Make sure, you've really got it, when you are running your app, not just as a part of your project in some IDE or somewhere else.

And check the path from your bean configuration… Suppose, there are not enough some / between {MYPROJECT_HOME} and log4j.properties

```
<value>file:///{MYPROJECT_HOME}log4j.properties</value>
```

There are 2 other ways to resolve it, if you are sure, you have a properties in a right place. First of all, you can set a JVM option, to show the path to your properties file:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///somepath/log4j.properties
```

Or you can configure it like this:

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();
```

But in this case all your logging will be only to System.out, so it may be not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response, **there is no problem with finding/loading the log4j.properties file, the ONLY problem is that the log4j warning comes even before loading the spring context object.**
I have tried your JVM property option "-Dlog4j.configuration", even then I am still facing the warning during start up.